# IDE for PHP development and Drupal?

Tags: php, drupal, ide

What tools are available for developing PHP programs. I'm particularly looking for something that can hook into Drupal so you can step through code and add breakpoints. Basically, a Visual Studio for PHP would be the best. Anyone know of this? Can you guys maybe mention what you currently use (even if it's just mentioning the text editor)? What is the industry standard?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There is an article on how to configure eclipse/pdt for drupal on drupal.org: [Configuring Eclipse](http://drupal.org/node/75242)

You may also want to take a look at the [complete list for development tools](http://drupal.org/node/147789), as there are a lot of tools listed you may find helpful.

Comment: +1 for Eclipse PDT. You may want to check out nWire for PHP. It makes it easier to dive into massive amounts of existing code: http://www.nwiresoftware.com/products/nwire-php

Answer (score 16):

[NetBeans](http://www.netbeans.org/) with [XDebug](http://www.netbeans.org/kb/docs/php/debugging.html).

Comment: +1 Netbeans PHP support is excellent and keeps improving.

Comment: NetBeans and Eclipse are both great. I found NetBeans to be a bit slower than Eclipse, and that's why I'm using the latter.

Comment: just download the development version, not the stable one

Answer (score 4):

Aptana Studio 
http://www.aptana.com/
Free & Open source
Fully Javascript / DOM Support

Answer (score 3):

[Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/) is a great ide. Can step through code in debugging using e.g [xdebug](http://www.xdebug.org/). Code completion is good

Answer (score 2):

So, why don't you download Visual Studio for PHP ???
http://www.jcxsoftware.com/

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for a all-round IDE which is fast and minimal I'd go for: Sublime Text 2
[www.sublimetext.com/2](http://www.sublimetext.com/2)

Answer (score 1):

PHPEd is a fantastic PHP IDE  for Supported platforms for Windows 98, ME, 2000, 2003, XP, Vista

It has a lot of the functionality of Visual Studio.

http://www.nusphere.com/products/phped.htm

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse integrates really well with Drupal

Answer (score 1):

I've been meaning to try out [Delphi for PHP](http://www.embarcadero.com/products/delphi-for-php) for simply ages, but haven't gotten around to it yet.

Here's the [download link](https://downloads.embarcadero.com/free/delphi_for_php) for a free trial, would be worth investigating.

Answer (score 1):

I'm fond of [Komodo Edit](https://www.activestate.com/products/komodo-edit/), which you can get for free, or pay the cash for [Komodo IDE](https://www.activestate.com/products/komodo-ide/).

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse PDT gets it done for me.

Answer (score 1):

[PHP Storm is awesome.](http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/) It focuses on integrating lots of modern best practices and technologies, for example [Code Sniffer](http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/features/index.html#PHP_Code_Sniffer) and even has support for [Drupal coding standards](http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/features/index.html#Drupal_Coding_Style_Support).

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to pay $399 for a year of subscription, you may try [Zend Studio](http://shop.zend.com/en/zend-studio-for-eclipse.html). Actually a good text editor like vim and emacs (I personally use vim) is fairly enough for PHP development I think.

Comment: How would you compare Zend with Eclipse?

Comment: Actually Zend Studio is not something new: it's based on Eclipse.

Comment: Not necessarily: Studio 5.5 and below is native. Only Studio 6 and later are based on Eclipse PDT. You can still obtain Studio 5.x when purchasing a current license, and it is often more convenient/efficient than the Eclipse-based version, especially regarding remote browsing on top of FTP or SFTP/SSH.

Comment: Also note that 399 is for a perpetual license, not a yearly one. Only the support is yearly. For most serious PHP development, you'll want an IDE anyway: Zend, PDT, Netbeans, Nusphere, whatever, but more than just an editor, especially for things like debugging/profiling or documenting.